# Ubuntu grub2 wont let me boot from hard drive

Tags: 16.04, grub2, usb

I am a beginner in Linux, please be patient with me :) I have Ubuntu is file on a USB stick, and I am trying to wipe out Windows 10 and install Ubuntu 16.04. When I reach grub2, and I install Ubuntu, when I press F 12 it only gives me the option to boot from my USB, not my HDD. Also, when I choose the option to install again, it says that Ubuntu is already installed, and that I need to install it alongside Ubuntu! Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you turn off, remove the USB and turn on the computer without pressing F12 etc?

Comment: Perhaps your laptop has secure boot and it prevents Ubuntu from installing, in all cases go into Ubuntu live mode from the USB and paste the output of the command `sudo fdisk -l` here for more clarity please.

Answer (score 0):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=297261

That site might help you in your journey in ubuntu.
In my case, I really did start all over again. To check my bootable flash drive and that I haven't downloaded a busted OS and then start installation again. And maybe you'll find a question in the middle of Installation about UEFI( again in my case, I selected GO BACK) maybe you could just continue and then it'll install the system.